# How to assign a variable into a class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, uwp

Im stuck at a problem and could use some help. So this is roughly my code:

```
x.cs
    using References;
....

namespace Name
{
....
public sealed partial class ReaderPage : Page, View.Listener
{
....

private View view;
.....

class MyMenuFlyoutItem : MenuFlyoutItem

   {
    public MyMenuFlyoutItem()
    {
        this.Click += MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click;

    }

private void MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
        dataPackage.SetText(view.vSelGetText());
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }
   }
....
 }
}


y.cs
....
        public String vSelGetText()
       {
        ....
        }
....
```

Now my Problem is that "view" in the class MyMenuFlyoutItem throws an error on me. How is it possible so the class MyMenuFlyout takes the view from x.cs for dataPackage.SetText(view.vSelGetText());?
The error is: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property x.view"

Comment: Um.. what error does it throw? NullPointerException? Be more specific in your question of what the problem is when you attempt x.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry @Adriani6.
The error is this: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property x.view"

Comment: Where is the vSelGetText() method defined? You should post your actual code in a minimal form when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access *non-static* field `view` of a `ReaderPage` class from instance method of a `MyMenuFlyoutItem` class. Despite the fact that `MyMenuFlyoutItem` is [nested class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) of `ReaderPage` and/or is declared in the same file, these classes and their instances are completely independent to each other. Think of it as if `MyMenuFlyoutItem` was not declared as nested:

```
public sealed partial class ReaderPage : Page, View.Listener
{
    private View view;
}

class MyMenuFlyoutItem : MenuFlyoutItem
{
    private void MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
        // cannot access view
        dataPackage.SetText(view.vSelGetText());
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }
}
```

From the above is obvious, that `MyMenuFlyoutItem` needs some instance of `ReaderPage`, to access it's `view`, because there could be many instances of `ReaderPage` class and compiler would not know, from which of these instances should be the `view` read. Nested class has the advantage that is can "see" *private* members of parent class, but still you need to have a reference to the `ReaderPage`, from which you want the `view` to be read from.

One of several possible solutions to this problem is to pass a reference of a `ReaderPage` class to the `MyMenuFlyoutItem` constructor:

```
public sealed partial class ReaderPage : Page, View.Listener
{
    // Nested class can access this field despite being declared as private
    private View view;

    class MyMenuFlyoutItem : MenuFlyoutItem
    {
        private ReaderPage page;

        MyMenuFlyoutItem(ReaderPage page)
        {
            this.page = page;
        }

        public MyMenuFlyoutItem()
        {
            this.Click += MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click;
        }

        private void MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
            // Nested class can access field `view` of parent class, although `view` is declared private
            // but you still need `page` reference
            dataPackage.SetText(page.view.vSelGetText());
            Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
        }
    }
}
```